# Upload photo using 'fetch' in react native gave me network error

Tags: reactjs, networking, react-native, fetch, image-uploading

I'm building a react native app & trying to upload a photo to server & i'm using fetch, i've tried other solutions from the web but it didn't work.

this is my [code](https://gist.github.com/WilliamAnputra/10f4dff3ada5b937f3e2b1d2e0a27b46)

this is the error

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can show your full error ? and the gist is also not full!

Comment: Are you sending image data as binary stream? I can see you send it as a string? Show me how are you sending image data to the backend?